# Multiple threads reading random files

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, io

i have a thread pool and all threads have a fixed set of images. Let's say they have each 100 images. I need to detect which image contains another image that reside in an image bank.

- thread 1 - 100 images
- thread 2 - 100 images
- thread 3 - 100 images
- thread 4 - 100 images
- Image Base - 50 images

Now i need all the threads to look inside the Image base to see if one of the images they hold resembles one of the image base. I have my image matching done, what i am worried about is if multiple threads might open the same image file. What would be the proper way of tackling this ? It would be nice not to "lock" all the other threads for each IO.

Thanks !

Comment: If the only operation on those images is read, you shouldn't have concurrency issues (assuming no one else changes the images once the threads start processing)

Comment: You could use a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) to limit the number of threads that can concurrently access the images. Similarly, you could use a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) to ensure only one thread at a time can access the images.

Comment: I do not understand. First you say: `all threads have a fixed set of images`, but later you tell us: `multiple threads might open the same image file`... do or do they not have a fixed set of images?

Comment: each Threads have a list of images, List<Image> A and then they have to compare a images from A to a set of images that are stored on the hard drive, List<Image> B

Comment: Your explanation is unclear. Are there 400 different images? Or does each thread have the same list of 100 images that it's comparing to those in List B?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this, where each thread has a reference to the image bank and provides a delegate that will be called for each of the files in the image bank?  Here is a skeleton of what the image bank might look like.

```
public class ImageBank {
    public delegate bool ImageProcessorDelegate(String imageName);

    private readonly List<String> _imageBank;

    public ImageBank() 
    {
        // initialize _imageBank with list of image file names
    }

    private int ImageBankCount {
        get {
            lock(_imageBank) {
                return _imageBank.Count;
            }
        }   
    }

    private List<String> FilterImageBank(ISet<String> exclude) 
    {
        lock(_imageBank)
        {
            return _imageBank.Where(name => !exclude.Contains(name)).ToList();
        }
    }

    public void ProcessImages(ImageProcessorDelegate imageProcessor)
    {
        var continueProcessing = true;
        var processedImages = new HashSet<String>();
        var remainingImages = new List<String>();

        do
        {
            remainingImages = FilterImageBank(processedImages);

            while(continueProcessing && remainingImages.Any())
            {
                var currentImageName = remainingImages[0];
                remainingImages.RemoveAt(0);

                // protect this image being accessed by multiple threads.
                var mutex = new Mutex(false, currentImageName);             
                if (mutex.WaitOne(0))
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        // break out of loop of the processor found what it was looking for.
                        continueProcessing = imageProcessor(currentImageName);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        // exception thrown by the imageProcessor... do something about it.
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        // add the current name to the set of images we've alread seen and reset the mutex we acquired
                        processedImages.Add(currentImageName);
                        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while(continueProcessing);
    }
}
```

Then, each thread would have its list of images (`_myImageList`) and a `ThreadProc` that looks something like this:

```
void ThreadProc(object bank) 
{
  var imageBank = bank as ImageBank;
  foreach(var myImage in _myImageList)
  {
    imageBank.ProcessImages(imageName => 
      {
         // do something with imageName and myImage
         // return true to continue with the next image from the image bank
         // or false to stop processing more images from the image bank
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming all threads have the same set of images they have to work on, and assuming the pahts to these files are in a list or some other collection, you could try something like this:

```
// A shared collection
List<string> paths = new List<string>();
// Fill this collection with your fixed set.

IEnumerator<T> e = paths.GetEnumerator();
// Now create all threads and use e as the parameter. Now all threads have the same enumerator.

// Inside each thread you can do this:
while(true)
{    
    string path;
    lock(e)
    {
        if (!e.MoveNext())
            return; // Exit the thread.
        path = e.Current;
    }
    // From here, open the file, read the image, process it, etc.
}
```

In this example you only put a lock on the enumerator. Only one thread can read from it at the same time. So each time it is called, a different path will come out of it.

Outside the lock you can do all the processing, I/O, etc.

Of course the collection could also be of another type, like an array.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. I think i may have explained something wrong. Each image has to check all the images in the base. I think the way you implemented it, it only checks the base once ? Since e.MoveNext() will return a different path, each threads have to take each images they have and then check them againts the whole base.

Comment: So.. to be clear: You have one collection of 50 images which you need to 'compare against 4x100 images. So in total you have to do 50x400 = 20,000 'compare' operations. These 50 images are shared and these 100 images are unique for each thread?

Comment: That is exactly what i need to do.

Comment: Ah... now you are afraid that comparing to those 50 shared files will give a "collition"?

Comment: Why not first load all 50 shared images into memory and then process them? Or is that to big? Do you have to reload these images each time you start comparing?

Comment: I just did that. Loading all the images in memory before starting the proccess.